# R - Is there any way to incorporate a dataframe value inside a regex?

Tags: r, regex

I've got a dataframe that contains a three-letter element and the number of times it's repeated. It looks like this:

`View (df)`

| Element | RepeatNumber |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | 5 |
| BBB | 6 |
| CCC | 5 |
| DDD | 9 |
| EEE | 7 |

My intention is to create a loop so I can check if this small string (i.e., "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA") exists inside a larger string, and, if so, then locate its position and extract it. My problem isn't creating the loop, though. What I actually would like some help with is to capture the df$Element values and pass it to a regex.

For example, something along the lines of:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
   for (s in 1:length(sequences)) {
      if (grepl (x = fasta [s], pattern = "(df[1,1]){2,}") == TRUE)) {
         do ...
      } else {
         do ...
      }
   }
}
```

P.S.: the object `sequences` came from a fasta file and is a DNAStringSet, that's why I'm using `length (sequences)`.

Answer (score 0):

`pattern` accepts a character string, so we'll need to concatenate the regex expression from its static and dynamic parts before parsing it. This could be done using `paste0` or `sprintf` (@Roland). You might as well want to check out `glue`-package.

```r
paste0("(", df[i,1], "){2,}")
```

```r
sprintf("(%s){2,}", df[i,1])
```